# How do I query mongo for all docs where an array contains an object that in turn contains a specific property

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo collection where each document look something like this:

```
{
  title: "blah blah",
  stuff: [
    {
      id:"001",
      data:"blah blah blah"
    },
    {
      id:"002",
      data:"bleeh blah blooh"
    },
    {
      id:"003",
      data:"bow wow wow"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to find all documents where the 'stuff' array contains at least one object where 'id' is '001'.

My initial attempt was this:

```
db.mycollection.find({ stuff: [ { id: "001" } ] });
```

But evidently this is not correct.

What is the correct query?

Comment: Use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation). Something like `db.mycollection.find({ "stuff.id": "001" });`

Comment: @Veeram You should post that as an answer, it'll get an upvote from me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$elemMatch` operator

`db.mycollection.find(
   { stuff: { $elemMatch: { id: "001"} } }
)`

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Comment: Just fyi. [Single query condition](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#single-query-condition) don't require the use of `$elemMatch`.